# IOS Animated Imageview intercepts another image

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios7

So im new to objective-c and  i have a image that's moving up and down the screen at all times , how would i code if another image touches or intercepts that image . this is the animation code i have done , but still confused on how to write the second part. thank you for your help

Animation:

```
//LINE ANAMATION
layer = line.layer;
CGPoint startPoint = (CGPoint){line.center.x,20};
CGPoint endPoint = (CGPoint){line.center.x, screenSizeY/2};

CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath, NULL, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(thePath, NULL, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.duration = 3.f;
animation.path = thePath;
animation.autoreverses = YES;
animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
[layer  addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(self.imageView1.frame, self.imageView2.frame))  
{
   NSLog(@"Intersected!");
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"No intersection :(");
}
```

Comment: The Imageview is animating so it says its intersecting on its original position not the animating position